how to fix model boot method not working properly?
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->unique_id = self::generateUniqueId();
        });

        self::deleting(function (Submission $submission) {
            Log::info('Deleting model:', ['model' => $submission]);
            dd($submission);
            // Delete all associated media
            $submission->clearMediaCollection('files');
            $submission->clearMediaCollection('images');
        });
    }

i have this method in my submission model the creating works on each new model while creating but the deleting is not working it just deletes the model and this doesnt works
my submission model

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\File;

class Submission extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia, HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'unique_id',
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'description',
        'status',
    ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->unique_id = self::generateUniqueId();
        });

        self::deleting(function (Submission $submission) {
            Log::info('Deleting model:', ['model' => $submission]);
            dd($submission);
            // Delete all associated media
            $submission->clearMediaCollection('files');
            $submission->clearMediaCollection('images');
        });
    }

    public static function generateUniqueId()
    {
        do {
            $uniqueId = str_pad(rand(0, 99999999), 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        } while (self::where('unique_id', $uniqueId)->exists());

        return $uniqueId;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubmissionReply::class);
    }

    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('files')
            ->useDisk('submissions')
            ->acceptsFile(function (File $file) {
                return in_array($file->mimeType, [
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/png',
                    'application/pdf',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                    'text/plain'
                ]);
            });

        $this->addMediaCollection('images')
            ->useDisk('submissions')
            ->singleFile()
            ->acceptsMimeTypes([
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/jpg',
            ]);
    }
}


The issue is likely due to the use of dd($submission), which halts execution and prevents the media from being deleted. To fix this, remove dd() and add proper logging to ensure the deleting event is triggered and the media is cleared.
if you're using forceDelete(), the deleting event won’t be triggered. In that case, listen for the forceDeleted event instead
self::forceDeleted(function (Submission $submission) {
    $submission->clearMediaCollection('files');
    $submission->clearMediaCollection('images');
});


Please follow and Update in your code with that basic softDelete solution:

Add Soft Deletes Trait (if you use soft deletes):
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Submission extends Model implements HasMedia
{
use InteractsWithMedia, HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
}
Just import rest of code will be same as before.

Use forceDelete() to delete permanently:
Submission::find($id)->forceDelete();

Clear Cache:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear

Verify the Delete Operation in Code:
$submission = Submission::find($id);
$submission->delete();



Events are fired if you call delete on each model, not on the builder.
//events not fired
Submission::query()->delete();

//events fired
Submission::query()->get()->each->delete();

Live code example in laravel sandbox:
https://sandbox.ws/en/shared/e0eadb68-f145-46a2-9981-188ee3c34e8a
